# Error typecasting with va_arg using variable arguments

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I wrote this simple code to find average of numbers using variable arguments -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

double avg(int num, ...)
{
        va_list arg_list;
        double sum=0;
        int x;

        va_start(arg_list,num);

        for(x=0;x<num;x++)
        {
                double n=va_arg(arg_list,double);
                printf("Num = %f\n",n);
                sum+=n;
        }
        va_end(arg_list);
        return sum/num;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
        printf("%f\n",avg(2,2.0,4.0));
        return 0;
}
```

Each of the entered number is converted to double. But if I enter, say, 4 instead of 4.0 in the parameters passed to `avg()` in `main()`, the compiler cannot seem to type cast it properly. Can anyone point out the mechanism behind this?

Answer (score 3):

Of course, the compiler has no idea how you're going to be picking out the arguments in your call to `va_arg()` when it compiles the `avg()` call.

The types have to match, since for instance `int` and `double` often have different sizes. Depending on the exact mechanism the compiler uses to pass the arguments, this can lead to mis-matches if you put in a value of one size, and take out one of another. Not good, don't do that.

One way to get this safer is to use `printf()`-style specification strings, since many compilers check these so that the arguments match.

Comment: All is relative. A spec string is safer, yes. Avoiding C style `...` is *much* safer, and I think that deserves to at least be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a 4 it is not promoted because the argument is not on the parameter list. The 4 is passed as an int.

Your `va_arg` macro will cast the address of the variable on the stack as a pointer to double and dereference it, but the memory there represents an int.

It is basically doing this:

```
int a = 4 ;
double d = *(double*)&a ;
```

Not this:

```
int a = 4 ;
double d = (double)a ;
```